# The description of the product sigma-algebra for countable products

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

***This is taken from Folland 's analysis book.***

[image]

[image]

I basically got stuck on understanding the proof of proposition 1.3 .

I will appreciate if anyone can help to clarify.

P/S : Can anybody show me how to type math notation on this site ?

Comment: What part of the proof did you not understand?

Comment: I guess you better tell us what Lemma 1.1 is as well.

Comment: The mathematics used on this site is surrounded by '$' characters and is called MathJAX.  You can right-click on an expression and choose the "show math as" option to see what the original text looks like.

Comment: @Daniel. I dont understand how the inverse of the pi-alpha will equals the multiplication of set E betas. Okay, I will post the lemma 1.1 .

Comment: It's not the inverse, it's the preimage (or inverse image), $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha) = \{x = (x_\beta)_{\beta \in A} : \pi_\alpha(x)\in E_\alpha\}$.

Comment: Dang! Which means I don't understand a lot of things. This may result from the lacking knowledge of some basic stuff. If you can please explain it slowly and if I miss out something I will go back and review it.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but there is an error in your print of the book. In the first line of the proof of proposition 1.3, $E_{\beta} = X$ should be $E_{\beta} = X_{\beta}$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof, with more details. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the generating set that defines the product sigma algebra. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set in the proposition.

Firstly, notice that if we take an element of $\mathcal{E}$, it's an element of $\mathcal{F}$, hence an element of $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$. So Lemma 1.1 tells us that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ is contained in $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$.

Now, notice that if we take an element of $\mathcal{F}$, it's a countable intersection of elements of $\mathcal{E}$, hence an element of $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$. The equality follows by the definition of the product in terms of projections - i.e. that an element $x$ is in the product on the LH side if and only if for every $\alpha$, $\pi_\alpha(x)$ is in $E_\alpha$. So Lemma 1.1 tells us that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$ is contained in $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$.

Therefore, $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$ = $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$, which is exactly what we wanted.